# How to do the MySQL master-master replication with conflict resolution,auto sync after fail over

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, mysql-cluster

We have a business requirement in that, We need to do the MySQL Master-Master replication by solving the below possible issues.

1. Conflict resolution
2. Auto sync after MySQL server failure

Here, We are going to write the data in both the Master MySQL servers and the data should not get conflicted at any cost. Please help us to find the best way of MySQL replication in order to achieve our requirement.

Comment: You will have to come up with a table and application scheme that prevents conflicts as base replication doesn't handle them.  You could use autogen keys on each side with different starting numbers, you could attempt a GUID generation in the application because if you do it at the database, the statement will generate different GUID values and, while there won't be a conflict, you won't be able to identify the rows in each database.